# Adding a column to a dataframe based on aggregated data in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have

```
df1 <- data.frame (ID = c("A01", "B01", "C03"), meta=LETTERS[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame (C03 = c(15,25,35), A01 = c(10,20,30), B01 = c(20,20,30))
```

I need to attach to each level of ID in df1 the `colSums` information for this level in df2.

i know a very basic way to do this, but there must be much better ways to do this:

```
vec1 <- as.data.frame(colSums(df2))
vec1$ID <- row.names(vec1)

df.m <- merge(df1, vec1, by ="ID")
df.m  ### desired output

   ID meta colSums(df2)
1 A01    A           60
2 B01    B           70
3 C03    C           75
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `df1$ID` _perfectly_ matches the column order and names in `df2`? That seems like it might be fragile, and if the order is ever disrupted you would mis-assign sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
df1$Sum <- colSums(df2)[df1$ID]
```

-output

```
> df1
   ID meta Sum
1 A01    A  60
2 B01    B  70
3 C03    C  75
```

Comment: i should really have attended that basic R course in undergrad school. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `match`:

```r
df1$Sum <- colSums(df2)[match(df1$ID, names(colSums(df2)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also using `colSums`:

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>% mutate(Sum = colSums(df2)[ID])
```

```
 ID meta Sum
1 A01    A  60
2 B01    B  70
3 C03    C  75
```